# What are the reasons for UDP packets to be dropped by the network stack

Tags: linux, udp, iptables, packet

I see UDP packets arriving on my Linux box (via tcpdump) with destination port set to 25555. However:

```
nc -l -u 25555
```

shows no traffic.

I've already checked:

1. iptables is off
2. destination MAC address matches the incoming interface
3. destination IP address matches the incoming interface
4. IP checksum is OK
5. UDP checksum is OK

Also, *all* the packets are being dropped, thus it's not a problem with overlowing rx buffers.

Any ideas what else may cause the pakcets to be dropped?

Comment: What's the destination IP address?

Comment: Are you sure no other program is reading from that port?  Do `cat /proc/net/udp` and show us what it prints (when nc is not running).

Comment: I would expect nc to fail is such case (EADDRINUSE), no?

Comment: It does not. Interesting. Still, no other application is listening on that port. netstat -antelupa | grep 25555 gives no results.

Comment: I don't know for sure.  If you show us your `udp` table we can see more details.  If you don't want to post it, at least try grepping it for the hex representation of your port number.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'udp table'?

Comment: `cat /proc/net/udp` as I said.

Comment: The relevant line is: 104: 00000000:63D3 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 0 0 1779298 2 fff810266fe0c 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that the packets were dropped by RPF filtering. See net.ipv4.all.rp_filter setting in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You have another process on your machine which is reading the datagrams arriving on port 25555.  We can see it from your `/proc/net/udp`:

```
sl   local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr rexmits  tm->when uid timeout inode ref pointer   drops
104: 00000000:63D3 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 0   0       1779298 2 fff810266fe0c 0
```

So the process which is "stealing" the datagrams you want is owned by root (uid=0).  And the inode of the socket is 1779298, which you can search for under `/proc/PID/fd` for the PIDs owned by root.  Once you figure out what process is listening there, you'll need to decide whether to terminate it so `nc` can listen instead.

Unicast UDP datagrams will only end up going to a single process on a Linux system, even if there are multiple processes trying to read from that same address.

Comment: Nope. That's my nc process listening on 25555. When I kill it, the line disappers from the udp table.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear when I said "when nc is not running."  Oh well, good luck to you.